# How i can display a few elements from two dimensional array in one line?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to display an array in the form of a table, as I do in c ++, but it doesn't work correctly.

I was trying some format parameters on WriteLine(String, Object[]) syntax - "\n" or "\b", but when i use some parameter, cmd doesn't displaying anything.

C# code which currently I'm trying.

```cs
 for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Map[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
```

C++ code which I'm rewriting to C#.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            cout << tab[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

What I'm expecting:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

What I'm getting (without format parameter):

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
...
```

( It's my first post )

Comment: In your nested loop use `Console.Write`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you made a little mistake `Console.WriteLine` instead of `Console.Write`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
 {
      for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
      {
          Console.Write(Map[i, j]);
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
  }
```